# オーバーライドされた関数を基底クラスからの呼び分ける方法

Tags: python3

Python 3.9.10を使っています。

```
class cls_Common(object):

    def __init__(略)
        以下略

    def Process_A():・・・①
        以下略

    def Process_B():
        前略
        
        self.Process_A():
        
        以下略
```

---

```
class cls_main(cls_Common):
    
    def __init__(略)
        super().__init__(略)
        以下略

    def Process_Z():
        super().Process_B():
        以下略

    def Process_A():・・・②
        以下略
```

---

というクラス定義をした上で、

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
    
    CLS = cls_main(略)
    CLS.Process_Z()　・・・③
```

とした場合、Process_Aは、最終的に②が呼ばれるのではないかと思います。
③のような場所から呼び出す前提で、Process_B内（またはcls_Common内）に何らかの処理（条件分岐など）を埋め込むことで、Process_Aの①、②を呼び分けることは可能ですか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

やりたい事と合っているか分かりませんが、以下のように単純に`cls_Common`側に変数/パラメータ/メソッドを定義して、それを元に呼び出し先を変更出来ると思われます。
変数はクラス/グローバル変数などでも出来るでしょうから、お好みで。

```
class cls_Common(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rootmode = False    #### インスタンスにモード変数(例えばbool型)を定義して初期化
        print('Common.Init')

    def Process_A(self):
        print('Common.ProcessA')

    def Process_B(self):
        print('Common.ProcessB')
        if self.rootmode:       #### インスタンスのモード変数に応じて呼び先変更
            cls_Common.Process_A(self)
        else:
            self.Process_A()

    def Process_C(self, root):  #### モードを指定するパラメータを定義
        print('Common.ProcessC')
        if root:                #### 指定されたパラメータに応じて呼び先変更
            cls_Common.Process_A(self)
        else:
            self.Process_A()

    def Process_M(self, mode):  #### インスタンスのモード変数を変更するメソッド
        self.rootmode = mode
        print('Common.ProcessM')

class cls_main(cls_Common):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Main.Init')

    def Process_Z(self):
        print('Main.ProcessZ')
        super().Process_B()

    def Process_A(self):
        print('Main.ProcessA')

    def Process_Y(self, root):  #### パラメータを指定して呼び出すメソッド追加
        print('Main.ProcessY')
        super().Process_C(root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CLS = cls_main()
    print('-----------0')
    CLS.Process_Z()
    print('-----------1')
    CLS.Process_M(True)  #### cls_main側に対応するメソッドを追加しても良いがここでは直接呼出し
    print('-----------2')
    CLS.Process_Z()
    print('-----------3')
    CLS.Process_Y(False)
    print('-----------4')
    CLS.Process_Y(True)
    print('-----------5')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。反応が遅くなりすみません。こまめにやるしかないようですね。（派生先から呼ぶときは、super(). みたいなのがありますが、、、）